# Problem finding boost libs although they exist

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

I've downloaded boost to `C:\boost\boost_1_84_0\` with the following cmake file-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(cpptest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(cpptest main.cpp
        student.cpp
        student.h
)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\boost\\boost_1_84_0")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "C:\\boost\\boost_1_84_0\\stage\\lib")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories("C:/boost/boost_1_84_0")
    link_directories("C:/boost/boost_1_84_0/stage/lib")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_executable(cpptest main.cpp) # Replace with your actual files
    target_link_libraries(cpptest Boost::filesystem Boost::system)
endif()
```

I get the following error message -
`Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem system) (found version "1.84.0")`
although it does exsist in
`C:\boost\boost_1_84_0\stage\lib\cmake\boost_filesystem-1.84.0`

Comment: Are you mixing compilers? boost compiled for msvc will not work for MinGW or vise versa.

Comment: ***I've downloaded boost to C:\boost\boost_1_84_0*** Where did you get it? Did you download compiled binaries or did you compile them yourself by executing `bootstrap.bat` followed by `b2` in a shell / command line with your compiler settings enabled? The downloads at boost.org do not include compiled binaries so you will have to build them yourself with your compiler for the parts of boost that are not header only.

Comment: damn. so should i change my project to msvc or how can i build boost with minGW. pretty sure thats the case but the error message is not indicative about it

Comment: and yes i've executed bootstrao.bat and b2 , and again b2 with `b2 --with-filesystem --with-system `

Comment: You have to build boost with the compiler you want to use. If you built with msvc and want to use boost with MinGW delete the folder and start over with compiling boost with MinGW. Or an easier approach for MinGW is to use msys2 to provide your MinGW and boost using the package management in msys2 with `pacman`. If you use vscode the official instructions tell you to use msys2.

Comment: using clion. can i change the compiler to msvc? is it the same as visual c++?

Comment: [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC)